# Json to object and Mule expression

Tags: mule, esb

I have a json file which the link is https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Rajeun/b550fe17181610f5c0f0/raw/7ba82c6c1135d474e0bedc8b203d3cf16e196038/file.json

i want to do a test on the boolean "sent". there is my xml file.

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration"
        host="gist.githubusercontent.com" port="443" protocol="HTTPS"
        doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" />

    <flow name="testFlow">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration"
                path="Rajeun/b550fe17181610f5c0f0/raw/7ba82c6c1135d474e0bedc8b203d3cf16e196038/file.json"
                method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" />
        </poll>



        <json:json-to-object-transformer
            returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[payload.sent] == true )">
                <logger message="its ok" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <logger message="Error" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </flow>
```

errors:

```
ERROR 2015-03-25 16:29:59,871 [[push1].testFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to transform from "json" to "java.lang.Object"
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-109
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
 at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@1a09a5b; line: 5, column: 4] (org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException)
  org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser:1433 (null)
2. Failed to transform from "json" to "java.lang.Object" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.json.transformers.JsonToObject:132 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
 at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@1a09a5b; line: 5, column: 4]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:442)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

i don't know what is the problem please any help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression should be `<when expression="#[payload.sent == true ]">` and this is working for me ..

also as afelisatti mentioned, there should be a comma after **email** attribute in JSON payload

Comment: You'd better use `#[message.payload.sent == true ]`, as using `payload` alone sometime fails for no reason. Also `== true` is probably useless, try with `#[message.payload.sent]`only.

Comment: Completely agree with @DavidDossot

Answer (score 0):

There's is no comma after the "email" in that JSON file so the transformation fails, that's what the error message is saying. I believe the correct format would be

```
{
  "token" : 123,
  "tel" : 456,
  "email" : "Rm9vYmFyIQ==",
  "sent" : true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it wa useful two another questions. 1/ sent is true but i get this INFO  2015-03-25 17:14:16,156 [[push1].testFlow.stage1.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Error so the test not working well.
2/ How can i do the call once . because here i got an infinity of result until I stop compiling. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
```

and   use an json based mule expression #[json:sent]